# Is there a app / command that will hunt for files

Tags: command-line

Is there a app / command that will hunt for specified files ( thumbs.db, .m3u and similar ) files across my home dir and delete them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not forgetting the use of '*' in the search... use one of these. The find command has a delete switch, but it is more common to see and use the exec option.

```
find ~ -type f -name \*.m3u -delete
find ~ -type f -name \*.m3u -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Or you could use -regex not -name.

Comment: How would i make a script to print on the terminal what files it deleted? I ran find ~ -type f -name \*.m3u -exec rm -rf {} \;
 and did not get any message, just /home without any trace of .m3u :)

Comment: change the exec statement to: `echo "Deleting {}"; rm -rf {} \;`

Comment: @Oli: not so good. `find ~ -type f -name \*.m3u -okdir rm -rf {} \;` asks for confirmation.

Comment: I guess -delete is just newer, so you don't see it too often. Older gurus don't look into the man page any more. The `r` in `-rf` is wrong for `-type f`, but -delete would delete empty directories, if they're empty.

Answer (score 5):

None of the others are wrong, but before letting something off like this, make sure you test it without the `exec` or `delete` flags so you can just see what files it's matching!

eg:

```
find ~ -name "thumbs.db"
```

I might even go one further and say perhaps have the files moved into your trash (instead of being straight-deleted) so at least you can undo the process:

```
find ~ -name "thumbs.db" -exec gvfs-trash {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

That can be done from the terminal with the following command, use it with CAUTION:

```
find $HOME -name "thumbs.db" -exec rm {} \;
```

It will starting search your home dir for files matching that name and will execute rm (remove) on them.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and execute this command.

```
 find ~/ -name thumbs.db -type f -print | xargs rm -f
```

Comment: useless use of xargs.